# Remove rows based on factor-levels

Tags: r, data.table, subset, r-factor

I have a data.frame `df` in format "long".

```
df <- data.frame(site = rep(c("A","B","C"), 1, 7),
                 time = c(11,11,11,22,22,22,33),
                 value = ceiling(rnorm(7)*10))
df <- df[order(df$site), ]

df
  site time value
1    A   11    12
2    A   22   -24
3    A   33   -30
4    B   11     3
5    B   22    16
6    C   11     3
7    C   22     9
```

### Question

How do I remove the rows where an unique element of `df$time` is not present for each of the levels of `df$site` ?

In this case I want to remove `df[3,]`, because for `df$time` the timestamp 33 is only present for site A and not for site B and site C.

Desired output:

```
df.trimmed
  site time value
1    A   11    12
2    A   22   -24
4    B   11     3
5    B   22    16
6    C   11     3
7    C   22     9
```

The data.frame has easily 800k rows and 200k unique timestamps. I don't want to use loops but I don't know how to use vectorized functions like `apply()` or `lapply()` for this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another possible solution using the `data.table` package:

```
unTime <- unique(df$time)

library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(df, key = "site")

(notInAll <- unique(DT[, list(ans = which(!unTime %in% time)), by = key(DT)]$ans))
# [1] 3

DT[time %in% unTime[-notInAll]]

#      site time value
# [1,]    A   11     3
# [2,]    A   22    11
# [3,]    B   11    -6
# [4,]    B   22    -2
# [5,]    C   11   -19
# [6,]    C   22   -14
```

**EDIT from Matthew**
Nice. Or a slightly more direct way :

```
DT = as.data.table(df)
tt = DT[,length(unique(site)),by=time]
tt
   time V1
1:   11  3
2:   22  3
3:   33  1

tt = tt[V1==max(V1)]      # See * below
tt
   time V1
1:   11  3
2:   22  3

DT[time %in% tt$time]
   site time value
1:    A   11     7
2:    A   22    -2
3:    B   11     8
4:    B   22   -10
5:    C   11     3
6:    C   22     1
```

In case no time is present in all sites, when final result should be empty (as Ben pointed out in comments), the step marked `*` above could be :

```
tt = tt[V1==length(unique(DT$site))]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. The package does a very good job and is really fast. It takes less than 2 seconds for 2.711.520 rows!

Comment: @maxmagmilch, the biggest thanks should go to Matthew Dowle (the package's author and maintainer and an active presence on SO)!

Comment: @BenBarnes Hi, very kind thanks. Btw, did [presentation](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/LondonR_2012.pdf) from LondonR find its way to you. Interested in how it comes across "cold" as it were.

Comment: @MatthewDowle, thanks for the edit with the more direct logic. Something that just occurred to me would be a potential issue when there is no time present for all sites. But that's an easy check. And many thanks for the link to your presentation. I think it's very clear, and I had forgotten about the list columns capabilities - very handy! Also totally thrilled about `:=` by group in 1.8.1.

Answer (score 2):

Would `rle` work for you?

```
df <- df[order(df$time), ]
df <- subset(df, time != rle(df$time)$value[rle(df$time)$lengths == 1])
df <- df[order(df$site), ]
df
##   site time value
## 1    A   11    17
## 4    A   22    -3
## 2    B   11     8
## 5    B   22     5
## 3    C   11     0
## 6    C   22    13
```

Re-looking at your data, it seems that this solution might be too simple for your needs though....

### Update

Here's an approach that *should* be better than the `rle` solution that I put above. Rather than look for a run-length of "1", will delete rows that do not match certain conditions of the results of `table(df$site, df$time)`. To illustrate, I've also added some more fake data.

```
df <- data.frame(site = rep(c("A","B","C"), 1, 7),
                 time = c(11,11,11,22,22,22,33),
                 value = ceiling(rnorm(7)*10))
df2 <- data.frame(site = rep(c("A","B","C"), 1, 7),
                 time = c(14,14,15,15,16,16,16),
                 value = ceiling(rnorm(7)*10))
df <- rbind(df, df2)
df <- df[order(df$site), ]

temp <- as.numeric(names(which(colSums(with(df, table(site, time)))
                               >= length(levels(df$site)))))
df2 <- merge(df, data.frame(temp), by.x = "time", by.y = "temp")
df2 <- df2[order(df2$site), ]
df2
##   time site value
## 3   11    A    -2
## 4   16    A    -2
## 7   22    A     2
## 1   11    B   -16
## 5   16    B     3
## 8   22    B    -6
## 2   11    C     8
## 6   16    C    11
## 9   22    C   -10
```

Here's the result of tabulating and summing up the site/time combination:

```
colSums(with(df, table(site, time)))
## 11 14 15 16 22 33 
##  3  2  2  3  3  1
```

Thus, if we were interested in including sites where at least two sites had the timestamp, we could change the line `>= length(levels(df$site))` (in this example, 3) to `>= length(levels(df$site))-1` (obviously, 2).

Not sure if this solution is useful to you at all, but I thought I would share it to show the flexibility in solutions we have with R.