# How to remove duplicate rows based on three factor levels

Tags: r

I referred the following links, seem not to be appropriate for my question.

[Remove rows based on factor-levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137036/remove-rows-based-on-factor-levels)

[Remove row based on two factor levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046525/remove-row-based-on-two-factor-levels)

I have a data frame say as below.

```
  ZNF226  1  A
  ZNF226  1  P
  ZNF227  1  M
  ZNF227  1  P
  ZNF229  1  P
  ZNF229  1  A
   ZNF23  1  M
  ZNF230  1  A
  ZNF232  1  P
  ZNF233  1  A
  ZNF233  1  P
  ZNF234  1  P
  ZNF235  1  A
  ZNF236  1  P
  ZNF236  1  P
  ZNF238  1  A
  ZNF238  1  M
  ZNF239  1  P
   ZNF24  1  A
   ZNF24  1  P
   ZNF24  1  P
   ZNF24  1  P
```

I want to remove the duplicate rows. I want to retain the row with the preference of P>A>M in the third column. If rows has P,A,M then only the row with P will be retained. If A and M then A will be there with other duplicates removed and finally M. The expected output is below

```
  ZNF226  1  P
  ZNF227  1  P
  ZNF229  1  P
   ZNF23  1  M
  ZNF230  1  A
  ZNF232  1  P
  ZNF233  1  P
  ZNF234  1  P
  ZNF235  1  A
  ZNF236  1  P
  ZNF238  1  A
  ZNF239  1  P
   ZNF24  1  P
```

The number of rows is approx 70k. Thanks in advance.

Edited: Above the first and second row are duplicates. The fist row has `A` in 3rd column and second row has `P` in 3rd column. As i mentioned the preference will be `P>A>M`. So A has second preference after P. So drop row with `A`.

Now in the 3rd and 4th row. `P` has first preference to be retained so drop row with `M`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `data.table` for big datasets.  Convert "data.frame" to "data.table" (`setDT(df1)`). Grouped by "V1" and "V2", change the class of "V3" to factor by specifying the levels based on the preference ("P > A > M").  Get the index of "minimum" value of "V3" (`which.min`) and subset the "V3" (`V3[which.min(..)`]

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(V3=V3[which.min(factor(V3, levels=c('P', 'A', 'M')))]),
                                   .(V1, V2)]
 #       V1 V2 V3
 #1: ZNF226  1  P
 #2: ZNF227  1  P
 #3: ZNF229  1  P
 #4:  ZNF23  1  M
 #5: ZNF230  1  A
 #6: ZNF232  1  P
 #7: ZNF233  1  P
 #8: ZNF234  1  P
 #9: ZNF235  1  A
#10: ZNF236  1  P
#11: ZNF238  1  A
#12: ZNF239  1  P
#13:  ZNF24  1  P
```

Or a similar method with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
 df1 %>% 
    group_by(V1, V2) %>% 
    summarise(V3=V3[which.min(factor(V3, levels=c('P', 'A', 'M')))])
```

#### Update

Based on the new dataset

```
df2 <- read.csv('111.csv', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
str(df2)
#'data.frame':  2618 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ X : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
# $ V1: chr  "A1BG" "A1BG-AS" "A1CF" "A2LD1" ...
# $ V2: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ V3: chr  "P" "A" "A" "A" ...
res <-  setDT(df2)[, list(V3=V3[which.min(factor(V3,
           levels=c('P', 'A', 'M')))]), .(V1, V2)]
dim(res)
#[1] 1175    3
```

If we need to print all the rows of dataset in the R console, change the `options`

```
  op <- options(datatable.print.nrows=Inf)
  res[1:10,]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("ZNF226", "ZNF226", "ZNF227", "ZNF227", 
"ZNF229", "ZNF229", "ZNF23", "ZNF230", "ZNF232", "ZNF233", "ZNF233", 
"ZNF234", "ZNF235", "ZNF236", "ZNF236", "ZNF238", "ZNF238", "ZNF239", 
"ZNF24", "ZNF24", "ZNF24", "ZNF24"), V2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), V3 = c("A", "P", "M", "P", "P", "A", "M", "A", "P", "A", 
"P", "P", "A", "P", "P", "A", "M", "P", "A", "P", "P", "P")),
.Names =  c("V1", "V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -22L))
```

Comment: It gives some half results for me. M not sure if i am missing anything.

Comment: @dssunilkumar  Based on the input dataset, my solution is getting the expected result as you showed

Comment: U r right. Can u please check with this file https://www.dropbox.com/s/tynca5hm2vu0f0t/111.csv?dl=0

Comment: @dssunilkumar  I am not sure what is the expected output for the new dataset.  I get 1175 rows using the code

Comment: Can U please put that file for me.

Comment: Can u share that file with me

Comment: @dssunilkumar  Wouldn't it be easier for you to copy/paste the same code and get the result

Comment: thanks i got the same dim . its not displaying the data on the screen. When i write it by `write.csv(res,"1.csv")`, there the results are good

Comment: @dssunilkumar I think it is because of the print options on screen.  So, I guess this solves the problem

Comment: Other results it print but not this results. it prints 1,2,3,4,5 then ..... and then 1171 to 1175

Comment: You could change the options i.e. `op <- options(datatable.print.nrows=Inf); res`

Comment: So basically, the question was not "How to do this?", but "Can you do this for me?" I see...

Comment: @akrun I am trying to access the element at the location of df[2,1], but it gives me the value which is at the column location. say in df[2,1] it displays 1 but it has some other element at that location. How to access a single element in this case.

Comment: @dssunilkumar   Did you mean in `res`?  In the posted solution, there is no `df` object.  If it is in `res`, `res[2,1, with=FALSE]
#        V1
#1: A1BG-AS`

Comment: @akrun . Ok let it be res. I think i can access by res[[1,1]] , which shows the behaviour of nested data frame. It does not give access by res[1,1], Y so.

Comment: @dssunilkumar  Please check the updated comment.  `with=FALSE`

Answer (score 1):

Assign 1,2,3 to M,A,P accodringly, such as:

```
df$x[df$col3 == "M"] <- 1
df$x[df$col3 == "A"] <- 2
df$x[df$col3 == "P"] <- 3
```

Then use aggregate by column 1 and 2

```
df <- aggregate(df$x, list(df$col1, df$col2), max)
```

Then revert numbers to according letters.

Example provided by you, with rather crude read-in:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
ZNF226  1  A
ZNF226  1  P
ZNF227  1  M
ZNF227  1  P
ZNF229  1  P
ZNF229  1  A
ZNF23  1  M
ZNF230  1  A
ZNF232  1  P
ZNF233  1  A
ZNF233  1  P
ZNF234  1  P
ZNF235  1  A
ZNF236  1  P
ZNF236  1  P
ZNF238  1  A
ZNF238  1  M
ZNF239  1  P
ZNF24  1  A
ZNF24  1  P
ZNF24  1  P
ZNF24  1  P", sep = " ", header = F)

df <- df[-c(2,4)]
colnames(df) <- c("col1", "col2", "col3")

df$x[df$col3 == "M"] <- 1
df$x[df$col3 == "A"] <- 2
df$x[df$col3 == "P"] <- 3

df <- aggregate(df$x, list(df$col1, df$col2), max)
colnames(df) <- c("col1", "col2", "col3")

df$col3[df$col3 == 1] <- "M"
df$col3[df$col3 == 2] <- "A"
df$col3[df$col3 == 3] <- "P"
```

And output:

```
> df
     col1 col2 col3
1  ZNF226    1    P
2  ZNF227    1    P
3  ZNF229    1    P
4   ZNF23    1    M
5  ZNF230    1    A
6  ZNF232    1    P
7  ZNF233    1    P
8  ZNF234    1    P
9  ZNF235    1    A
10 ZNF236    1    P
11 ZNF238    1    A
12 ZNF239    1    P
13  ZNF24    1    P
>
```

Comment: Yes, it should work. Want me to make a reproducible example for you?

Comment: If u can please, that will be nice

Comment: gives me this error: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "x", value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 695

Comment: Does it give you error when you run your full data frame, or when you run my example?

Comment: the elements of `A ` alphabet https://www.dropbox.com/s/tynca5hm2vu0f0t/111.csv?dl=0

Comment: Then you should carefully check how column names of your data frame correspond to the code. Note that df$col1 ; col2 ; col3 is assigned to initial data frame and df$x is created in the process. Adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: I got my mistake but still i get some NA's in the third column.

Comment: Are you sure that there are only 3 possible values in the third column? You can check it by levels(df$col3).