# Remove duplicate rows

Tags: r, duplicates, data.table

Already this question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28763605/how-to-remove-duplicate-rows-based-on-three-factor-levels) ,but could not make it work.

I have a data frame here,interested to remove the duplicate rows based on `SYMBOL`. Checking the column `CALL` to remove the duplicates.The priority is `P>A>M`.If `P,A,M` keep `P`, if `A,M`, keep `A`, otherwise `M`.

```
      SYMBOL  INTENSITY  CALL
1     DDR1    596.95050    P
2     RFC2    420.28708    P
3     HSPA6   510.73254    P
4     DDR1   1717.99487    A
5     GUCA1A  121.53488    A
6     UBA7   1810.49780    P
7     UBA7    301.51944    M
8     GUCA1A   34.53987    A
9     CCL5   5966.24609    P
10    CYP2E1   95.15707    A
11    CYP2E1  164.95276    M
12    ESRRA  1024.88745    P
13    CYP2A6  502.48877    A
14    GAS6    921.70923    P
15    MMP14   524.96863    A
16    GAS6   3069.48462    P
17    FNTB    266.77686    A
18    PLD1    187.65569    A
19    PLD1   1891.04541    P
20    PLD1    258.79028    M
```

I tried the code which i found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28763605/how-to-remove-duplicate-rows-based-on-three-factor-levels)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(CALL=CALL[which.min(factor(CALL, levels=c('P', 'A', 'M')))]),
                                   .(SYMBOL)]
```

But i removes the second column `INTENSITY`. Any help, please make sure the code is fastest also. Thanks

Expected Output

```
          SYMBOL  INTENSITY  CALL
    1     DDR1    596.95050    P
    2     RFC2    420.28708    P
    3     HSPA6   510.73254    P
    5     GUCA1A  121.53488    A
    6     UBA7   1810.49780    P
    9     CCL5   5966.24609    P
    10    CYP2E1   95.15707    A
    12    ESRRA  1024.88745    P
    13    CYP2A6  502.48877    A
    14    GAS6    921.70923    P
    15    MMP14   524.96863    A
    17    FNTB    266.77686    A
    19    PLD1   1891.04541    P
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use `order` (in the `i`th position) to order the "CALL" column by converting to `factor` with the `levels` specified in the correct order, and subset the first observation (`.SD[1L]`), grouped by 'SYMBOL'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(factor(CALL, levels=c('P', 'A', 'M'))),
                                 .SD[1L], by = SYMBOL]
```

Or just modifying your code, instead of `list(CALL=..`, we can use `.SD` to subset the rows.

```
setDT(df)[, .SD[which.min(factor(CALL, levels=c('P', 'A', 'M')))], .(SYMBOL)]
```

An option using `dplyr` is

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(SYMBOL) %>%
    arrange(factor(CALL, levels=c('P', 'A', 'M'))) %>%
    slice(1L)
```

Or use `which.min` within `slice`

```
df %>%
    group_by(SYMBOL) %>%
    slice(which.min(factor(CALL, levels=c('P', 'A', 'M'))))
```